# Adding an app to Django

Tags: python, django

I tried adding an app to Django and named the app main. I typed django-admin.py startapp main.

When i run python manage.py runserver, i face this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 14, in <module>
    execute_manager(settings)
  File "/Users/cnnlakshmen_2000/Projects/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 459, in execute_manager
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/cnnlakshmen_2000/Projects/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 382, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Users/cnnlakshmen_2000/Projects/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 261, in fetch_command
    klass = load_command_class(app_name, subcommand)
  File "/Users/cnnlakshmen_2000/Projects/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 69, in load_command_class
    module = import_module('%s.management.commands.%s' % (app_name, name))
  File "/Users/cnnlakshmen_2000/Projects/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/Users/cnnlakshmen_2000/Projects/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/syncdb.py", line 8, in <module>
    from django.core.management.sql import custom_sql_for_model, emit_post_sync_signal
  File "/Users/cnnlakshmen_2000/Projects/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/sql.py", line 6, in <module>
    from django.db import models
  File "/Users/cnnlakshmen_2000/Projects/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    if DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS not in settings.DATABASES:
  File "/Users/cnnlakshmen_2000/Projects/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 184, in inner
    self._setup()
  File "/Users/cnnlakshmen_2000/Projects/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 42, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/Users/cnnlakshmen_2000/Projects/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 95, in __init__
    raise ImportError("Could not import settings '%s' (Is it on sys.path?): %s" % (self.SETTINGS_MODULE, e))
ImportError: Could not import settings 'main.settings' (Is it on sys.path?): No module named settings
```

Not sure how to solve the error...Need some guidance...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't give an app the same name as the project; Django will have trouble telling them apart.